# Inicializando Array de uma nova classe

Tags: c#, array, classes

Considerando duas classes em C#:

```
public class aClass
{
    public string afield;
}

public class bClass
{
    public aClass[] bfield;
}
```

Eu pretendo iniciar a variável como

```
bClass cVar = new bClass();
cVar.bfield[0].afield = "text";
```

mas está gerando o seguinte erro durante o debug.

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
>
> cVar.bfield was null.

**Como eu inicio a variável para evitar este erro?**

Comment: Nosso idioma é o **Português**, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Traduza sua pergunta, assim eu vou poder sinalizá-la como duplicata de `O que é NullReferenceException`. Respondendo: Você precisa inicializar o campo `bfield` ou na própria declaração do campo ou no construtor. Assim: `bfield = new [] { new aClass() { afield = "conteúdo" } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aparentemente o seu problema é que você não inicializou o "Array", para resolver você poderia inicializa-lo antes de atribuir algum valor:

```
bClass cVar = new bClass();

cVar.bfield = new bfield[] {
    new aClass {
        afield = "text";
    };
};
```

Ou

```
bClass cVar = new bClass();

cVar.bfield = new aClass[1];
cVar.bfield[0].afield = "text";
```

Porém com toda certeza esta não seria a melhor maneira de fazer o que você quer, um array não fornece toda a flexibilidade que você provavelmente busca, talvez seja melhor você optar por uma lista, poderia fazer assim:

```
public class aClass
{
    public string afield;
}

public class bClass
{
    public List<aClass> bfield = new List<aClass>();
}
```

```
bClass cVar = new bClass();

cVar.bfield.Add(new aClass {
    afield = "text"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a implementação mais fácil é criar uma propriedade iniciada inline

```
public class bClass
{
    public aClass[] bfield => new aClass[10];
}
```